# I can't access a user input in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am developing an apt management app.

I managed to get all functions to work but I am having trouble with the last one.

Basically, user selects one of the 5 update options from the db update menu page by clicking one of the submit buttons numbered from 1 to 5.

Button#5 is for updating the monthly apt fee. User enters the new monthly fee and clicks the update button.

But no matter what I do, I can't access the user input in `req.body.newFee`.

When I display it at the console, node displays it as undefined. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Below is my main server.js file.

```
    // Send login page file to the client.
    app.get('/loginpg', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile("D:/Behrans-files/Web-projects/havuzlusite/loginpg.html");
    });

    app.post('/server', (req, res) => { //Post request to receive user login data that was posted to server.js by login form. 
        var usrname = req.body.isim; 
        var usrpwd = req.body.sifre;
        
        if (usrname && usrpwd) {  //Check if user has entered name and password in the login form.
            if (usrname == 'Yonetim' && usrpwd == "admin") {  //If building management name and pwd entered,  
                res.render('dbupdmenupg');  //Display db update menu page.
                
                //Route to handle db update menu page.
                app.post('/dbupdmenupg/:btnno', (req, res) => {  // Get the number of clicked button.  
                    console.log("newFee1: ", req.body.newFee);
                
                    // Route to handle apt fee payment - If button#1 was clicked.
                    if (req.params.btnno == 1) {   
                        res.render('usrpmtpg');  //Display user apt fee payment page.
                        app.post('/', (req, res) => {  //Post request to access payment month and payment amount inputs from user.  
                            var usrname = req.body.usrname;
                            var pmtmnth = req.body.pmt_mnth;
                            var pmtamt = req.body.pmt_amt;
                            queryUsrName(usrname, function(response) {  //Pass usrname and call function to see if the user is in db.
                                console.log('status_flg: ', response);
                                if (response == 'Found')  { //If response has no error message, call function to update user payment data in db.
                                    updateUsrPmtData(usrname, pmtmnth, pmtamt, function(response) { //Call function to update user apt fee payment data in db.
                                        alert(response);   //Display db update status message from called function.
                                        res.render('usrpmtpg');
                                    });    
                                } else if (response == 'Not found')
                                            alert('İsim veri tabanında bulunamadı. Ana sayfaya dönmek için lütfen Ana sayfa butonuna tıklayınız!'); //If response has error message, display error message.     
                                        else 
                                            alert('Site sakini ismi veri tabanında aranırken sorun oluştu.');
                                        })        
                        })
                    }     
                    // Route to handle deletion of existing resident user - If button#2 was clicked.
                    if (req.params.btnno == 2) {  
                        res.render('deluserpg');
                        app.post('/', (req,res) => {
                            var usrname = req.body.usrname;
                            queryUsrName(usrname, function(response) { //Pass usrname and call function to see if the user is in db.
                                if (response == 'Found')  { //If response has no error message, it means user is in db, call function to delete it.
                                    deleteUser(usrname, function(response) { // Pass username input data as parameter to call deleteuser function.
                                        alert(response);  //Display db delete status message from called function.
                                        res.render('dbupdmenupg');
                                    })  
                                } else if (response == 'Not found') {
                                        alert('İsim veri tabanında bulunamadı. Lütfen sistemde mevcut bir isim girin.'); //If response has error message, display error message.     
                                        res.render('deluserpg'); 
                                        } else 
                                            alert('Site sakini ismi veri tabanında aranırken sorun oluştu.');                                               
                            })
                        })

                    }     
                    // Route to handle addition of new resident user - If button#3 was clicked.     
                    if (req.params.btnno == 3) {
                        res.render("adduserpg");
                        app.post('/', (req,res) => {
                            var usrname = req.body.newname;                        
                            queryUsrName(usrname, function(response) { //Pass usrname and call function to see if the user is in db.
                                if (response == 'Found') {
                                    alert('Isim veri tabaninda mevcut, tekrar eklenemez. Lütfen sistemde olmayan bir isim girin. '); //If response has error message, display error message. 
                                } else {
                                    //If response has error message, it means user is not in db, call function to add it.
                                    addUser(req.body.newname, req.body.newpwd, req.body.newblokno, req.body.newdaireno, req.body.newaidat, function(response) { //Pass input data as parms to call addUser funcn.
                                        alert(response); 
                                    })    
                                }
                                res.render('adduserpg');
                            })
                        })
                     } 
                    // Route to handle reseting residents for the new year - If button#4 was clicked.  
                    if (req.params.btnno == 4) {
                        newyearReset(function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                        })
                    }
                    **// Route to handle updating apt monthly fee - If button#5 was clicked. 
                    if (req.params.btnno == 5) {
                        res.render('updfeepg');
                        app.post('/updfeepg', (req,res) => {
                            newFee = req.body.newFee;
                            console.log("newFee: ", newFee);
                            if (newFee) {
                                aptfeeUpdate(newFee, function(response) {
                                    alert(response);
                                })
                            }
                        })
                        res.end();**
                    //    res.redirect("/dbupdmenupg");   
                    }        
                })        
                    
            } else  {  //If a resident user name and pwd entered, call function to query on name/pwd in database.
                    queryUsrNamePwd(usrname, usrpwd, function(rows) {
                        if (rows) {  // If user name/pwd match db, 
                            res.render('userdatapg', {rows});  // Display resident data.
                         } else    
                            res.redirect('/loginpg');     
                    }) 
              }
        } else //if no user name and pwd entered, display message 
            alert('Lütfen isim ve şifre giriniz!');
        //res.end();    
    });
```

Below is the html form file updfeepg.html.

```
    <body>
        <! Create database update menu form >    
        <form class="updfee" action="/updfeepg" method="post">
            <p class="parag" >Lütfen yeni aylık aidatı giriniz.<input type="number" class="newFee" id="newFee" max="999"></p>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="updfeebtn" name="updfeebtn" id="updfeebtn" >Aidatı güncelle</button>
            <a href="http://localhost:3000" type="button" class='homepg-btn'>Ana sayfa</a>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Registering new routes within another route does not make any sense. I'm not sure what  exactly you want to achieve with those `app.post('/dbupdmenupg/:btnno', (req, res) => {` and others in your `app.post('/server', (req, res) => {`. Where did you read that you should do it that way?

Comment: Especially the `if (usrname && usrpwd) { if (usrname == 'Yonetim' && usrpwd == "admin") {` with the routes registered in there looks highly suspicious. It looks like you want to have those rouse only active when the user is logged in. But you actually activate those roots for everyone as soon as one person entered the right username and password. And those routes will be active for everyone until the application restarts. And those multiple `app.post('/', (req, res) => {` look even more suspicous.

Comment: It looks to me as if you completely misunderstood how expressjs works.

Comment: I had to have routes within routes because you can't use the local variables of a route outside that route.  In my case, I need the username & pwd inputs from the first post request but since I can't use them outside that post request, with my limited technical knowledge, I could only get it to work with other post requests within the first one. I would love to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238170/discussion-between-behran-meydaner-and-t-niese).

Comment: You would need to ask that as a different question. And create a [mcve] about what you want to ask. If a user logs in and based on that you want to allow a subsequent request to do further action based on the login state, you need to enable session handling. (you can use existing middleware for that or create your own one). That middleware will add an additional property (in most cases `session`)  to the request object, that allows you to store session-related data in it and to retrieve that information in a subsequent request.

Comment: Dear t.niece, I did further research re session variables and changed my code as you suggested. I am attaching my own variables to req.session object as req.session.loggedin, req.session.userid and req.session.userpwd. I now authenticate username and userpwd inputs from login page in the first post request and if they match in db then I set req.session.loggedin to true. I was hoping that I would be able to use the req.session.loggedin and req.session.username variables in other requests but unfortunately it doesn’t work because I get undefined error.

Comment: Perhaps I am still doing something wrong but at the moment I can’t progress any further. I would like to include my minimal reproducable example but I don’t know how to do it because this is just a comment. My original question already had the my code included but I don’t know how to include new code in a comment.

Comment: The changes you did completely changed what you originally asked. In the original question, you asked about not being able to access `req.body.newFee` now it is about `session`. Due to that the answer given by Ayzrian doesn't match the question anymore. Please create a new question instead. I rolled the question back to its previous state (you can still see that other question as [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69584867/3) and copy it from there to a new question)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the body firstly before you could access it.

For that you can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

UPD:
The issue is here

`<input type="number" class="newFee" id="newFee" max="999">`

You need to have `name` field here. The `name` field defines the name of that value in the body of the request.

Try this.

`<input type="number" class="newFee" id="newFee" name="newFee" max="999">`

Comment: I am already using Express bodyparser module. It must be working because I am able to access the other inputs.

Comment: Bodyparser doesn't parse the form input, afaik.

Comment: Oh I see the issue

Comment: @BehranMeydaner see my comment again. I have updated it.

Comment: I knew it was something simple but I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks, it works now.

Comment: How do I mark the answer as correct? I also have another question related to this. Per T.Niese's rightly so negative comments blasting my coding, I did further research re session variables. My understanding is that I can assign my own variables to req.session properties and use them to structure my coding based on if the user is logged in or not. So I changed my code to do that. However, when I run my app, node.js says the req.session variables are undefined.

Comment: It seems like the req.session variables are no different from req.body variables because they are both accessible within the post request but not outside it. If so, I have no choice but to register routes inside other routes to make my app work. If this is the case, then T.Niese's negative comments are baseless. So the question is: Can I access the req.session variables outside the post request? If so, why am I getting the undefined error from node?